# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql

I need to run a python script when server start . 
I add in rc.local /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/test.py , for this I have error 
import mysql.connector as mysql 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' 
When I removed connection to mysql , is ok 
I tested : python3 /usr/sbin/test.py working good , connection to mysql
is ok .  
I try  
sudo python3 /usr/sbin/test.py - same error - 
import mysql.connector as mysql 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' 
mysql connector installed is : pip3 install mysql-connector-python
I dont have experience with linux , I think is chmod problem , but where ....?
Solved with : sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python

Comment: Did you install the MySQL bindings for Python (the 'mysql module')?

Comment: If I run script from python3 /usr/sbin/test.py , is ok , connect to db , write in table .<br>If run sudo python3 /usr/sbin/test.py , I have that error

Comment: Do not add new information in comments. Comments are not intended for conversation. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1446028/edit) instead. Make your question as clear and understandable as you can, and keep improving it until you get an answer.